# photoelectric effect and Quantized energy state

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I know that the energy state electron  is quantized.
for example if n1's energy is 1 and n2's energy is 3
electron only absorbs 2 energy. it never absorbs 1 or 2.5 energy.

but i learned that if the frequncy of light is just higher than threshold frequency of metal, than photoelectron is emitted immediately.
if

how it can be? i heard that there are virtual energy state but not exact. i hope you answer me everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is transition of electrons between the different energy levels in an atom/molecule. One of the necessary conditions for that to happen is that the energy of the photon should match the energy difference between the energy levels.

However, if the photon possesses enough energy for the electron to overcome the attractive forces of the metal and escape the lattice, it will absorb the energy and escape the metal. If the energy of the photon is just enough for the electron to overcome the attractive forces, it will escape without any kinetic energy. Frequency of light at which this happens is called the threshold frequency. For frequencies higher than the threshold frequency, the electron escapes with a kinetic energy equal to the difference between the energy of the photon and the energy required for the electron to overcome the attractive forces.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i have another question. my professor said electron can be excited even the light is lower than threshold frequency. when electron excited by low f, than there are an 'virtual energy state' or 'imaginary state' so, electron excited and go the 'virtual energy state' . the energy state is not 'real' so he said it does not have to follow the 'law of the conservation of energy'. he said this maybe 1~2 month ago. so i can't remember what he said exactly. do you know anything about this?

Comment: Virtual energy states are not eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (but can be constructed as a superposition of the eigenstates) and hence are not measurable or observable. We can postulate the existence of such states based on the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Such models are usually invoked to explain otherwise forbidden transitions; I have never heard anything about virtual states in the context of photoelectric effect before. Maybe you should ask your professor about it? Also, have a look at this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135177/what-is-a-virtual-state

Answer (score 0):

You described the excitation of an electron. The effect in the photoeletric effect is ionization. The electron absorbs the photon the excessive energy is converted into kinetic energy. If the electron has a higher kinetic energy than the work required to leave the metal, it can be detected as photo-current.